# Convert Xamarin.Forms.Color to platform specific color

Tags: android, ios, colors, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a way to convert a Xamarin.Forms.Color to a platform specific color. For example the Android.Graphics.Color for Android.

I took a look at the properties of the Xamarin.Forms.Color like R, G & B. The values only contain a 0 or 1 so that seems to be pretty worthless. Has someone experienced and solved this issue before?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I guess you try to do this in a custom renderer.

**In iOS**, you'd do:

```cs
UIColor uicolor = yourXFColor.ToUIColor ();
```

**In Android:**

```cs
Android.Graphics.Color adColor = yourXFColor.ToAndroidColor ();
```

Unfortunately, the equivalent extension methods are not public **for WP**, but you can do this:

```cs
System.Windows.Media.Color wpColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb (
            (byte)(yourXFColor.A * 255),
            (byte)(yourXFColor.R * 255),
            (byte)(yourXFColor.G * 255),
            (byte)(yourXFColor.B * 255));
```

then eventually:

```cs
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush (wpColor);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working. I was trying it in a class being used by a custom renderer. Now I'm transforming the color @ the renderer and passing the platform specific color to the object.

Comment: I suppose `xpColor` @ the last line of your answer is a typo?

Comment: Just FYI, the lack of the extensions on Xamarin.Forms made me add this to Xamarin.Forms.Labs (open source community XF add-ons): https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.WP/Extensions/ColorExtensions.cs

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix I can't find any extentions like `ToAndroidColor ();`

Comment: It seems that now, the extension method to convert Xamarin.Forms.Color to an Android color is: `XFColor.ToAndroid();`

Answer (score 16):

Currently you can do this with the "ToAndroid()" extension method in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
Android.Graphics.Color droidColor = formsColor.ToAndroid();
```

Answer (score 3):

Going off of the previous answers here, but Xamarin has now placed the ToAndroid() method in a ColorExtensions helper class.

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android
....
Android.Graphics.Color color = ColorExtensions.ToAndroid(formsColor);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some approaches for Windows:

Take e.g. [this](https://gist.github.com/peterfoot/be89d5b3c5ac4cc16ae1) extension:

```
using System;

namespace Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT
{
    public static class ColorExtensions
    {
        public static Windows.UI.Color ToWindows(this Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
        {
            return Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToByte(color.A * 255), Convert.ToByte(color.R * 255), Convert.ToByte(color.G * 255), Convert.ToByte(color.B * 255));
        }
    }
}
```

Or use a `Brush` directly like [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/58865/#Comment_58865):

```
var converter = new ColorConverter();

Control.CurrentBrush =
    (SolidColorBrush)
        converter.Convert(Element.CurrentLineColor, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Xamarin have added](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/ColorExtensions.cs) `ToWindowsColor()` (I think at 3.6 release). ->

Then it's just needed to do.. `YourColorObject.ToWindowsColor()` and then you've a `Windows.UI.Color`

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `Xamarin.Essentials`:

```
var xfColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromRgba(219, 52, 152, 255);

// Extension to convert
// using Xamarin.Essentials;
var platformColor = xfColor.ToPlatformColor();
```

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/color-converters